# How to make custom coloured closed caption for videos in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, closed-captions

See this video with caption on (**Warning:** Contains violent language but of not such a great deal. Its just a animation)
https://youtu.be/Hk_S1mbfsQA
This video have **animated color caption**. I cannot change the color from the settings

Can anyone say what did he do to achieve that?

Comment: I remember read a question here on Stack Overflow about this specific issue; I don't have the URL, but, you can search related questions to yours. In that question, I do remember the captions file has the color embed in it, something like: `<p from="105" to="112" color="#3ca4ff">Hello World</p>` - please search and [edit] your question with your results.